# Polynomial or wave through aligned points

Tags: trigonometry, lagrange-interpolation, weierstrass-factorization

If I have the distinct points $(x_{1}, 0) ... (x_{n}, 0)$,

A) What would be a simple polynomial (non-constant) passing through these points? And could I instead also write a simple continuous curve (a function) using the sine function?

B) Intuitively, I would expect that, by necessity, such a (continuous) polynomial or wave must change sign at each point, in order to be able to go through all points (without being a constant). How can this intuition be justified formally?

C) Imagining that the set of points becomes arbitrarily large (and they are equispaced, as a further simplification), is it true that the polynomial converges to a definite curve (for instance, a sinusoidal)? And why?

Comment: The constant function equal to $0$ works, did I miss your point ? Otherwise $P = \prod_i^n (X-x_i)$ works too.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right, I was implicity meaning a "non-trivial" (non-constant) function. Let me specify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your last question, is it indeed true (but not obvious) that

$$
\frac{\sin  x}{\ x}=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right) =\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{x}{n\pi}\right)\left(1+\frac{x}{n\pi}\right)  
$$

As $\frac{\sin x}{ x}$ has infinitely many roots $\pm\pi, \pm2\pi, \pm3\pi ...$ and it can be seen as a limiting product of an interpolating polynomial with an arbitrary large degree.

Comment: Wasn't this in fact how Euler claimed to "prove" the infinite product equality?

Comment: It was used by Euler in order to solve Bale's problem, but I believe he didn't prove it rigorously (for today standards).

Comment: I would wonder why to divide by x. In the case of equidistant points, I would imagine that a simple wave should do. No? Also, why not a sequence of semicircles or semiellipses?

Comment: I guess (not sure) you can multiply by $x$ on both side to get the root at $x=0$ if needed. I did not particularly spent much time on this. And you have anyway infinitely many functions that would do the job, here it's just probably the most intuitive function you'd use as the limit of a product polynomial with growing degree.

Comment: Yes I think you are right about the  infinitely many functions.  But if we take the simple product of $(x-x_{i})$ as you previously suggested, what would be the limiting form of this? still a sin wave ?

Comment: The hysterical and highly frustrated nonsense of "closing" question. I just don't get it.